# QML is not recognising C++ functions

Tags: c++, qml, integration

I am trying to implement my c++ class into QML, the class is recognised by setting the context property and I can successfully call the class and see all the functions but on runtime they are not recognised and returns the error:
TypeError: Property 'getSrcImage' of object Wrapper(0x7b211cbf10) is not a function, I believe that the functions are not getting properly declared to the QML but do not know how to fix..

.h file

```
class Wrapper : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_INVOKABLE void initiateLipLib();
    Q_INVOKABLE bool setMat();
    Q_INVOKABLE QImage displayfeed();
    Q_INVOKABLE void getMatFeed();
    Q_INVOKABLE int liptrainstart(cv::Mat Image);
    Q_INVOKABLE void liptrainingend();
    Q_INVOKABLE float getDistance();
    Q_INVOKABLE std::string getstatus();
    Q_INVOKABLE void clear();
public:
    explicit Wrapper(QObject *parent = 0);
    QString getSrcImage();
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QtQml/QQmlContext>
#include <QDebug>
#include "wrapper.h"



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("wrapper", new Wrapper);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

.qml

```
Image {
            id: camfeed
            visible: false
            source: wrapper.getstatus()
            anchors.centerIn: camcontainer
}
```

Comment: Did you try not having the functions private?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your Q_INVOKABLE functions needs to be `public` inside your wrapper object, and I hope you know that if not set to `public`, they are `private`.

Try switching them to public an retry.

```
class Wrapper : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Q_INVOKABLE void initiateLipLib();
    Q_INVOKABLE bool setMat();
    Q_INVOKABLE QImage displayfeed();
    Q_INVOKABLE void getMatFeed();
    Q_INVOKABLE int liptrainstart(cv::Mat Image);
    Q_INVOKABLE void liptrainingend();
    Q_INVOKABLE float getDistance();
    Q_INVOKABLE std::string getstatus();
    Q_INVOKABLE void clear();

    explicit Wrapper(QObject *parent = 0);
    QString getSrcImage();
```

Comment: That was where I had all the functions at first, I tried switching them round as I have seen other examples where they have been declared just beneath the Q_OBJECT macro..

Comment: If it's not working, you should try initializing Wrapper first `Wrapper* wrap = new Wrapper();` then put it in context : `engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("wrapper", wrap);`

Comment: And care, your functions name cases does not respect anything, QML is case sensitive

Comment: In my case, the error was due to methods being `private` rather than `public`

Answer (score -1):

The solution was to change the Q_INVOKABLE to Q_PROPERTY, defined the functions in public then called them within my qml. All functions seem to be working correctly and returning the correct values.